# Capcha Community Builder

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I recently installed Community Builder for Joomla!. I can't seem to have a capcha image included in the registration form. Is there a plugin that I can use? That will make the implementation fast and effective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Captcha plugin available to CB subscribers: [link](http://www.joomlapolis.com/content/view/3906/37/)

Comment: I decided to use AUser, Community builder is great but if I need to pay, I can't use it

Comment: The non-commercial EasyCalcCheck Plus is another solution: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/captcha/11964